# Select X that has both Y and Z (SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok, I have three tables, `Colors`,`People`,`Likes`

`Colors` contains ids and names colors, `People` contains ids and names of people, `Likes` contains `color_id` and `people_id` to describe which people like which colors.

Now, given a list of colors, how can I select every person (if any) who likes every color in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select p.id, p.name
from people p
join likes l on l.people_id = p.id
join colors c on l.color_id = c.id
where c.name in ('blue','green','red')
group by p.id, p.name
having count(distinct c.name) = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can GROUP BY the person joined on the Likes, and retrieve those tuples HAVING a COUNT(*) equal to the number of rows in the Color list. This way you

- only need to join two tables
- don't need to explicitly name the colors.

```sql
SELECT People.id, COUNT(*) AS ColorsLiked
    FROM People JOIN Likes ON (People.id = Likes.people_id)
GROUP BY People.id
HAVING ColorsLiked = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Colors);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM People p 
INNER JOIN Likes l ON l.people_id = p.people_id 
INNER JOIN Colors c ON l.color_id = c.color_id 
WHERE c.name IN ('List of colors')
```